# How to populate all the Test Suite created in Katalon Studio in an excel file?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I am trying to populate all the test suites that I have in the Katalon Studio into an Excel.

To be specific, is it possible that if a new test suite is created in Katalon it gets automatically populated in the excel?